# Manipulating Data in an HTML File

Tags: python, html

I am using python and I have an HTML file that has a table containing the sample name, gene name, and number of cases and controls in the experiment. Like this...

```
Sample    Gene     Cases,Controls
snow      NGF       1,2
sun       NGF       2,3
sun       NGF       1,0
snow      NGF       1,3
```

I need to separate the cases and controls into 2 separate columns and then also add columns for corrected cases and corrected controls. So if the sample, is snow, the # of cases has to be multiplied by 0.8 and if the sample is sun, the # of controls has to be multiplied by 1.5. I am not sure how to identify the cases and controls in the line and then assign the case and control to different variables so that I can manipulate them.

Comment: It didnt show up right but the snow/sun is supposed to be underneath the sample column, NGF is supposed to be underneath the Gene column, and the numbers(ie 1,2) is suppoed to be underneath the cases, controls column

Comment: this might help: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/ d

Comment: What do you have so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: _It didnt show up right_.  Then keep editing your question until it does show up right.

Comment: Could you please post the actual HTML for the table, and what you'd like the final HTML to be?

Answer (score 1):

Try out the pandas library for this. Make sure to install lxml as well.

First off, let's pretend this is your html:

```
<table>
<tr><th>Sample</th><th>Gene</th><th>Cases,Controls</th></tr>
<tr><td>snow</td><td>NGF</td><td>1,2</td></tr>
<tr><td>sun</td><td>NGF</td><td>2,3</td></tr>
<tr><td>sun</td><td>NGF</td><td>1,0</td></tr>
<tr><td>snow</td><td>NGF</td><td>1,3</td></tr>
</table>
```

I'll also assume you read that into a variable called `html`.

```
import pandas
tables = pandas.io.html.read_html(html,header=0,infer_types=False)

# Pandas reads each table read from the HTML into a list,
# we only have one here
table = tables[0]
```

That made a [DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/dsintro.html#dataframe) with your table.

[image: panda dataframe]

Which you can now operate on, pandas style! In particular, you probably want to pull out cases and controls.

```
# Break out those cases and controls into a DataFrame
case_control_list = table["Cases,Controls"].str.split(',',1).tolist(),
case_control = pandas.DataFrame(case_control_list, columns = ["Cases", "Controls"])
```

[image: case control pandas]